# String Similarity algorithm

Tags: string, similarity, fuzzy-search

I want to use string similarity functions to make a fuzzy matching.
In my case, I search for many words in a big list. these words can be a whole sentence so their size in most of the times will be big.

I came upon several of similarity algorithms:

Jaro,
Jaro-Winkler,
Levenshtein,
Levenshtein using kb-tree
Q-gram,
I wanted to know what will they work best in my case? Or if there is another way to implement fuzzy matching?

I try this in a 45,000 word and it takes 8 minutes using Jaro-Winkler and it's so expensive

Comment: You forgot one of the oldest "fuzzy string match" algorithms of them all: [soundex](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Soundex).

Comment: but it is only apply for English.My app should be applied for all language so I want solution to be generic ?